# Let $\mu$ denote the true average reaction time to a certain stimulus....

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

Let $\mu$ denote the true average reaction time to a certain stimulus. For a $Z$ test of $H_0: \mu = 5$ versus $H_a: \mu > 5,$ determine the p-value for each of the following values of the z test statistics

a) 1.41

b) 0.95

c) 1.96

d) 2.45

e)-0.12

i just need someone to help me solve a)
I will do the rest on my own

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Background: For $n$ observations from a normal population with standard deviation $\sigma,$ the statistic for testing $H_0: \mu=5$ against $H_a: \mu > 5$ is $Z=\frac{\bar X−5}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}} \sim \mathsf{Norm}(0,1),$ under $H_0.$

(a) For a one-sided test, the P-value is the probability $P(Z>1.41)$ of getting a more extreme observation than 1.41 (in the direction of $H_a$).

In R statistical software, where `pnorm` is the CDF of a standard normal distribution, the statement `1 - pnorm(1.41)` returns 0.07926984.

Now, do you know how to find this result using printed tables of the standard normal CDF? And do you know what this result says about rejecting $H_0$ at the 5% level?

In the figure below, 0.0793 is the area under the standard normal curve to the right of the vertical dashed line. Your printed normal tables may show the
the area between the two vertical lines.

[image]

If you still have questions about the procedure, please try part (c) and edit your work into your
Question. Then maybe one of us can find the difficulty.

Comment: Check: `z = c(1.41,.95,1.96,2.45,-.12); 1 - pnorm(z)` returns
0.079269841, 0.171056126, 0.024997895, 0.007142811, 0.547758426.